# Git archive adding not versioned file to subdirectory

Tags: git, subdirectory, archive

Trying to make zip archive with such command

**git archive -v -o app.zip --add-file=.env --add-file=.ebextensions/my-scripts.config HEAD**

2 not versioned files are added via **--add-file** option.

Problem is that my-script.config added to the root of archive, but I need it inside .ebextensions folder as it was initially.

Is there any way to achieve it with **git archive** command?

Comment: "*Problem is that my-script.config added to the root of archive…*" This is how `git archive --add-file` [works](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive#Documentation/git-archive.txt---add-fileltfilegt) — files are added at the [`--prefix`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive#Documentation/git-archive.txt---prefixltprefixgt), default is the root. "*Is there any way to achieve it with `git archive` command?*" Most probably no. You can try use `zip` to add the file after `git archive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't documented anywhere, so I'm not sure how much you should count on it, but testing shows that it works:

```
git archive -v -o app.zip \
    --add-file=.env \
    --prefix=.ebextensions/ --add-file=.ebextensions/my-scripts.config \
    --prefix= HEAD
```

(all as one line without the backslash-newline, or leave in the backslashes in sh / bash) does the trick with Git version 2.34.  Based on the code, it should work in all the versions of Git that have `--add-file` (2.29 and later).  Essentially, `--prefix` sets the *current* prefix; `--add-file` adds a file whose pathname consists of the prefix plus the tail part of the path, and `--prefix` then *replaces* the prefix, so that you don't have to affect the rest of the action.

Comment: Yeah, it works! Thanks a lot! 
Just little correction for subfolder prefix path, it should be --prefix=.ebextensions/

Comment: @AndreyK: Yes, I found that out while testing, then forgot to put it in the text above, oops. Will fix.